# MySql Ranking users

Tags: mysql, ranking

I am using this code to rank users:

```
    SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, userid, amount
FROM (
  SELECT userid, sum(amount) AS amount
  FROM leads WHERE date(time)='2013-09-15'
  GROUP BY userid
  ORDER BY amount DESC
) t1 , (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

The result is like this:

```
rank    userid  amount
1         11    1.15
2         10    1.15
```

It keeps adding rank even if the user has the same amount, any ideas how to fix this? Yes, I have searched google and here on stackoverflow, but I have not been able to fix this problem.

Comment: "It keeps adding rank even if the user has the same amount" ... You're saying that in case of a draw the users must have the same rank position?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a subquery to do what you want.

The following does a dense ranking of the amounts, by introducing another variable to remember the total amount:

```
SELECT userid, sum(amount) AS amount,
       if(@amount = amount, @rn, @rn := @rn + 1) as ranking,
       @amount := amount
FROM leads cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @amount := -1) const
WHERE date(time) = '2013-09-15'
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

Comment: For some reason it returns rankings in wrong order, highest amount will be last and lowest first ranked.